# Can we have two different apk(one custom and one general) from one project

Tags: android

I have developed an android application and am planning to publish it on play store.

However when i went to discuss it with a few people, i got custom requirements specific to their needs.

My question is, is it possible to generate two different apk files from the same code. One would have the extra custom code and one without it. If so please guide me as to what approach needs to be taken for this or if there's tutorials for this, tell me what i need to look for.

Comment: Sure you can. Here you go https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html and https://medium.com/@iammert/android-product-flavors-1ef276b2bbc1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read about Flavors in Android.

It should be exactly an answer to your problem. this is mainly used for "free VS paid" use-cases but can be a perfect match for you.

Flavors works by defining two package names for the same code.

After setting 2 different Flavors, you can simply query with an if-else on the Flavor and do what you need depending on the "project" you are working on.

[Android Flavors](https://proandroiddev.com/advanced-android-flavors-part-1-building-white-label-apps-on-android-ade16af23bcf)

[Configure Build Variants](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html)

Comment: Thanks man, I'm looking into it right now and as you said, looks like it's what i need. Will have to learn it though :) accepting your answer as the correct one.